# How do I edit a meta field?

Tags: wordpress

Good morning! I have a small problem with a Wordpress site. Basically our site contains information above the main menu. Before, this info, was editable via a meta field directly from the Wordpress back end on the HOME page, now (since I upgraded to Wordpress 5 and 6) this meta field to change those dates above the menu I can't find it. How can I solve? I tried looking at the .phps from the file manager but can't find that section. Could you help me?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Good Morning. If these were default custom fields from WordPress then you should check in top right screen option whether "custom fields" are checked/enabled. In latest WordPress versions with Block Editor Enabled, you will find this option when you will click on 3 dots on Top right and then in Preferences>>Panels [image: Enable Custom Fields]

Comment: Hello Khawaja Awais,
in the meantime, thanks for the answer. I followed your advice, but there is no "custom fields" in my preferences.
How can I solve?

Comment: Hello @Alessandro, without knowing how Meta Fields are created on your site (using built-in fields or using plugin like ACF or Metabox or through custom PHP), it will not be possible to help.  Thank you!

Comment: I found the solution: from file manager I went to the wordpress theme folder and modified the functions.php file by adding this string of code: add_filter ('acf / settings / remove_wp_meta_box', '__return_false');

Problem solved! You can close the discussion if you want!